# Storing LARGE PDFs in PSQL or ....?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, pdf, file-upload, psql

I'm working on my first application trying to upload multiple large to massive PDFs and be able to access them according to which project they were uploaded to in the application. The internet is pulling back and forth on if I should even be storing the PDFs in PSQL or not. The application will need to be able to upload and download these PDFs and be able to find them via the project the user is viewing.

I have seen Gems that 'help' but I am not that comfortable with this new territory. Is PSQL capable of handling LARGE PDFs??

My stack is currently PSQL, Ruby on Rails, and React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a PDF in the database as a binary field if you really want to. However, I do not recommend that, as it may clog up the DB connection due to the volume of data being transferred.

A better option would be to store the file in a filesystem, using a service like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/s3/), and save only the URL for the file in the database. Using [Rails Active Storage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) or [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) (for older Rails versions, before 5.2) will help you integrating with these services.